# A tiny fire-breather

Tags: biology, dragons, zoology

My postulated creature will look something like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

Its description is as follows:

- it's a non-obligate carnivore
- its height is, on average, about two feet
- it lives in arid habitats
- it DOESN'T fly

Regarding its fire ability:

- since it's a ruminant, it is able to burp out methane
- this is boosted by the help of a throat sac similar to that of either a frog or a frigate bird, not used to amplify its call but to store that methane gas
- similar to snake venom, it has a special sac connected to its teeth that will store either a pyrophoric liquid or hypergolic liquid
- it will use this fire to defend itself and to cook its food for easy digestion

So:

- **How many times would it be able to shoot out fire (or belch out methane gas)?**
- **What pyrophoric or hypergolic liquid could it use or store in its sac?**

I'm open to suggestions as to how to improve my creature in general, as well.

Comment: "Height"? Neither of those looks two feet tall, and if the second one is, I would hardly describe it as "tiny". It would be better, I think, to give us a meaningful comparison. Is it the size of an average dog? A housecat? A gecko? About how much does it mass?

Comment: You may want to look up terry pratchetts swamp dragons.

Comment: @John: I came here just to make a reference to Lady Sybil Ramkin. Glad to see it wasn’t just me that thought of it.

Answer (score 4):

2. **Pyrophoric liquid is ethanol**.

[An isolated cellulolytic Escherichia coli from bovine rumen produces ethanol and hydrogen from corn straw](https://biotechnologyforbiofuels.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13068-017-0852-7)

> A cellulolytic strain, ZH-4, was isolated from Inner Mongolia bovine
>   rumen. This strain was identified as Escherichia coli... This strain
>   was found to produce 0.36 g/L ethanol and 4.71 mL/g hydrogen from corn
>   straw with cellulose degradation ratio of 14.30% and hemicellulose
>   degradation ratio of 11.39%.

This fermenter made hydrogen and ethanol, not methane and ethanol.  I suspect that there will be one reduced carbon end product per fermenter so either methane or ethanol / methanol.

I could imagine a fire breather which added some oils it synthesized in its own body to its pyrophoric liquid.  The ethanol or methanol could be doped with biogenic lipids - something like whale oil.  Not easy to light but possessing loads of heat energy.  These would catch fire from the burning alcohol and gas but not burn up, rather landing on the target and continuing to burn there,

**1.  It will store enough for one blast.**

This thing is not a hunter.  Its breath weapon is strictly defensive for use on threats.  If you are trying to dissuade a predator there is no point in being subtle and saving enough for a second shot.  Give it all you got because you might not get another chance.

Like baby rattlesnakes who expel all the venom they have when they bite in defense, your fire breather will expel maximum fire onto the predator, and then will have to recharge over some days.  Plus if you evert your flame sac and expel everything you are at less risk for a backburn to your reservoir which might make you explode.

Comment: what if i want to breath, ok at least 4 times, is it possible

Comment: Baby rattlesnakes actually *don't* fully empty their venom into you when they bite; that's a myth. People just think they do, as they have a significantly lower tendency to do a "dry bite" (no venom) than adults do.

Comment: @user3556983 - sure 4 times is possible.  You can have it be how you like.  Or maybe your creature has 4 flame sacs and empties one per breath.

Comment: ok, so what if my creature is a carnivore and uses this fire to cook its food and as a defense, will it be different or the same?

Comment: You could have a carnivore use acetone as the pyrophoric fluid; acetone is produced from breakdown of fats (even in humans) and is as flammable as ethanol.  Keep the oil.  Anything counting on flammable fluids, whether a dragon or a car or a flamethrower, will come to a point where they run out unless magic.  You could have small flames for cooking and one big flame for defense.  I am skeptical abut hunting w flame breath but maybe like a Komodo dragon - burn the prey and then track it for days while it slowly dies of infection.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this in a documentary about hypothetical dragon evolution! Their proposal was that the dragon uses hydrogen to fill various bladders in its body and lighten itself to ease flight in a forested environment. Methane might work, but digesting a lot of simple plant matter would make it too heavy. It would be a picky eater. The more the dragon breathed fire, the smaller it got and the worse its flying characteristics would become. I don't remember the source, sorry. I can't claim credit. If it didn't have to fly, weight would be a less critical factor.

Comment: I think I saw that! It was originally on Discovery IIRC. Heavily inspired, most likely, by [The Flight of Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flight_of_Dragons_(book)). (Ahem. Smaller *and heavier*.)

Comment: my dragon is flightless